# Eclipse ADT bug - using wrong ResId

Tags: android

Today I noticed a very strange bug - the system used the wrong ResId in the method SetBackgroundResource(). Sure I thought it was my mistake. I fixed the ResId by copying and pasting it from the R file. After I've re-installed the app many times for testing I noticed that a wrong image was set again so it messed up my app. I went to the corresponding method and found out that Eclipse inserted a very similar (but wrong! ..015 instead of ..016) ResId as a method parameter without any actions from me.

I don't think that's important but this strange thing always happens here:

```
LinearLayout nlap = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10, 5, 10, 0);
nlap.setLayoutParams(params);
nlap.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
nlap.setBackgroundResource(0x7f020016);
nlap.getBackground().setAlpha(111);
return nlap;
```

Comment: Try cleaning your project. And its not a good practice to hard-code Res Id values, always access them using`R.id.resId'

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478052/android-adt-moving-views-mixes-up-ids-bug?

Answer (score 0):

Just clean all your related projects and build again.

Never hard-code a R.id.

I've seen this before: With old versions of ADT and library projects this would sometimes happen. Haven't seen it with ADT 21.

Recently, for me, Eclipse has started underlining R.id's red as if they are wrong or unknown, but they do not show up in the Problems view, and they are not actually wrong. I'm still looking for a bug report for this.

Comment: And please actually file bug reports here: http://b.android.com. File under Component-Tools. What's holding you back to do that in the first place?