# Android ADT: Moving views mixes up IDs (bug?)

Tags: android, adt, paste

I've been having a really annoying problem that I suspect is an Android ADT bug (v21.0.0-519525).

Let's say I'm working on an Activity with two views - a TextView on top and an ImageView on the bottom. I want to move the TextView from the top to the bottom. If I either click or drag it in the GUI, or I cut/paste it in the XML, everything looks fine on the preview and the XML code, but when I go to run the app, their IDs seem to get mixed up. Code which casts R.id.textView to a TextView throws an error because it now thinks that R.id.textView is an ImageView.

Has anyone else run into this? Is there a way around it?

Comment: One thing to mention: after moving it, changing the ID of the TextView in the XML and Java seems to fix it (but is obviously unideal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of problem sometimes happens when playing around with layout IDs.

One solution is to clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: Perfect, cleaning the project fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: What about if we don't want to clean each time because we then loose the benefit of all the pre-dexing? This really seems like a build-process bug somehow.